# Execute func after first func

Tags: swift

`self.werteEintragen()` should start after `weatherManager.linkZusammenfuegen()` is done. Right now I use `DispatchQueue` and let it wait two seconds. I cannot get it done with `completion func` because I dont know where to put the `completion function`.

This is my first Swift file:

```
struct DatenHolen {
    let fussballUrl = "deleted="
func linkZusammenfuegen () {
        let urlString = fussballUrl + String(Bundesliga1.number)
        perfromRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }

    func perfromRequest(urlString: String)
    {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task =  session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeFile = gettingInfo {
                    self.parseJSON(datenEintragen: safeFile)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            
        }
    }

    func parseJSON(datenEintragen: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedFile =  try decoder.decode(JsonDaten.self, from: datenEintragen)
            TeamOne = decodedFile.data[0].home_name
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my second Swift File as Viewcontroller.

```
class HauptBildschirm: UIViewController {
    func werteEintragen() {
            Tone.text = TeamOne

        }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            weatherManager.linkZusammenfuegen()

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [unowned self] in
                self.werteEintragen()
            }
        }
}
```

How can I implement this and where?

```
func firstTask(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    // Do something

    // Call completion, when finished, success or faliure
    completion(true)
}




firstTask { (success) in
    if success {
       // do second task if success
       secondTask()
    }
}
```

Comment: `func perfromRequest(urlString: String, completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void)) {... if let safeFile = gettingInfo {...} completion(true)} `

Comment: I had the same Idea already but then it says that there is an missing argument for parameter completion in call for this line: perfromRequest(urlString: urlString) It suggest to change it to this: perfromRequest(urlString: urlString, completion: <(Bool) -> Void>) But then I need to fill in something for Bool-Void. And I dont know what to fill in.

Comment: Double click on it? It's the same way you wrote `firstTask { (success) in`...

Comment: @zuzuzuzuzu please select the answer which helped you. If none helped you, post additional info.

Comment: Till now no answer helped me. I try my best to implement the suggestions. @Larme I double click on it and then? What do I have to write in it? I don't get what you mean with it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a completion handler which will notify when a function finishes, also you could pass any value through it. In your case, you need to know when a function finishes successfully.

Here is how you can do it:

```
func linkZusammenfuegen (completion: @escaping (_ successful: Bool) -> ()) {
    let urlString = fussballUrl + String(Bundesliga1.number)
    perfromRequest(urlString: urlString, completion: completion)
}

func perfromRequest(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (_ successful: Bool) -> ()) {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task =  session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
               print("Error: ", error!)
               completion(false)
               return
            }

            guard let safeFile = gettingInfo else {
               print("Error: Getting Info is nil")
               completion(false)
               return
            }
            
            self.parseJSON(datenEintragen: safeFile)
            completion(true)
        }
        task.resume()
        
    } else {
        //can't create URL
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

Now, in your second view controller, call this func like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    weatherManager.linkZusammenfuegen { [weak self] successful in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if successful {
                self.werteEintragen()
            } else {
                //do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `guard let self = self else { return }` is pretty *objective-c-ish* and not needed in Swift. There is ***Optional Chaining*** `self?.werteEintragen()`

Comment: Yes, but in case you want all your code to execute inside the completion, you would keep a strong reference to `self`, otherwise, there is a potential risk of some objects relying of `self?...` to be nil.

Comment: First of all thank you. I tried your code and get two errors. First is in the line with let task = ... It says "weak" may only be applied to class and class-bound. The second error is in the line with super.viewDidLoad and it says Missing argument for parameter " completion" in call

Comment: @zuzuzuzuzu I am sorry. I failed to notice it was a `struct`, and thus, it cannot be `weak`. It is value type. I updated my response (just removed the `[weak self]` from the `dataTask`'s completion handler). Regarding the `Missing argument for parameter " completion" in call` - it might be due to the previous error. Try the new code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Now I only get one error. It says: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion' in the line with let task = ...

Comment: Jesus ))) I forgot about that)) Now I updated the code again. This time it should work. Sorry, I wrote the code without testing it.

Comment: In general, API completion should use `Result<Type, Error>` but this is good enough as an example.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But it is very slow. It took about 6-10 seconds to show the result in the simulator. With my code above which waits 2 secondes after the first func it takes max 3 seconds. The Api shouldn't be a problem. When running your Code the console opens and it gives some code. I copied some of them here:

Comment: =================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:]
PID: 18061, TID: 2452353, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x7feb5f039350 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   myTeam                              0x0000000106db432f $s6myTeam15HauptBildschirmC14werteEintragenyyF + 383
5   myTeam                              0x0000000106db66c6 46
...

Comment: This is due to the fact that the `session.dataTask(with: url)` is being called on the background thread. You either have to call each completion on the main thread, or just do the next tasks on the main thread, in your `viewDidLoad` section. See my another edit.

Comment: Also, it was slow just because the `Main Thread Checker` found a problem. When it will be called on the correct thread, you won't see it lagging.

Comment: Checked your last edit and it takes now about 2 seconds which is fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Our whole conversation is a complete course on how to make asynchronous API calls with completion handler )))

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Google's Promises Framework:

https://github.com/google/promises/blob/master/g3doc/index.md

It is well explained and documented. The basic concept works like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import Promises

struct DataFromServer {
   var name: String
   //.. and more data fields
}

func fetchDataFromServer() -> Promise <DataFromServer> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        //Perform work
        //This block will be executed asynchronously
        //call fulfill() if your value is ready
        //call reject() if an error occurred

        fulfill(data)
    }
}

func visualizeData(data: DataFromServer) {
    // do something with data
}

func start() {
    fetchDataFromServer
    .then { dataFromServer in
        visualizeData(data: dataFromServer)
    }
}
```

The closure after "then" will always be executed after the previous Promise has been resolved, making it easy to fulfill asynchronous tasks in order.

This is especially helpful to avoid nested closures (pyramid of death), as you can chain promises instead.

Comment: Potato, potahto. I myself don't see any benefit from using Promises instead of native closures. Plus, it looks as if the OP is just starting with iOS development, and it will be a great burden for him to learn a 3rd party framework in order to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Well in this case you have a point, as there is only one task performed after another, however with multiple tasks performed in a specific order, closures become really tedious and error prone. I just wanted to share an alternative to keep in mind, especially if others stumble across the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I never used Promises, but I feel that each task can have its own completion, and you could just pass the `completion` into the next task, and the next, and so on. I myself rarely had a chain of more than 2-3 tasks which needed to be done one after another. Hard to think about a scenario where someone would need to chain 4 and more tasks.

Comment: Thank you I will look at it later if I fail to implement the other suggestions.